# How can I convert this AS400 query to one I can run in a JDBC-connected DBMS?

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

We have an old AS400 at my office that almost nobody there knows anything about, and a few legacy programs that interact with it. While looking around at some of the programs I found a file containing a query that caught my attention. I am great at SQL when working with an Oracle database (I worked a few years in a data warehouse querying Oracle 8 hours a day), but I have no experience with DB2 (or RPG/SQLRPGLE, which I think this is based on my searches) and this query seems completely foreign to me. Here is the query (slightly altered for data security/anonymity purposes):

```
SELECT
  WDATA(CVTDATE(PRDADT,CYMD)) NAME(@PRDADT) COLHDG("Availability Date"),
  WDATA(prdid.1) NAME(product) COLHDG("Product ID"),
  prdsku.1 EDTCDE(4),
  prcxif.2,
  sum(prcval) NAME(@price) LEN(6,2)
FROM
  mydb/prod T01,
  mydb/pric,
  mydb/vndr T02,
PARTIAL OUTER JOIN
  prdid.1=prcid.2
  and prdsku.1=prcsku.2
  and prdid.1=vnid.3
WHERE
  prdcbp=&CBP
  and prdadt BETWEEN yymmdd(date("&&startdt")) AND yymmdd(date("&&enddt"))
GROUP BY
  prdsku.1,
  prcxif.2
ORDER BY
  prdsku
```

I am having trouble making sense of some of the stuff here. I've gathered that the slash in the table name is a DB2-specific way to [separate schema/table](https://www.itjungle.com/2013/06/19/fhg061913-story02/), cvtdate indicates we use a program/utility called Sequel Data Access, and EDTCDE appears to be a way to [format output values](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzakc/rzakcmstdfedtcd.htm), but after hours of research I still can't find the answer to some questions (primarily because Google doesn't interpret symbols in most searches):

- What is the LEN(6,2) after the summed field? I assume it does some sort of padding/rounding (like a max length or a zero-padded length of 6 digits, with two decimal places) but any time I search for "len" Google gives me results that have "length" in them, or I find queries that seem to use the function with only one argument to get the length of a string.
- What are the ".#" postfixes on some of the column names? It isn't used in the ORDER BY so it doesn't look like it's actually in the field name; it looks more like it references which table in the FROM list the column belongs to. However, when playing around with another DB2 database, I don't have to do anything like that for joined tables, I just prefix them with the table name like Oracle... Also each column name seems to use a table-specific prefix so I don't know why it is necessary to identify the table.
- What are the &[text] and &&[text] objects? I think &CBP represents a passed parameter, but I don't know why it has one & symbol while &&startdt and &&enddt have two; perhaps a sort of escape character since those are in quotes?
- What does WDATA do? The second WDATA line appears to apply a format to a column before it gets used later (in the conditions) but the first one seems to apply a name/heading to a column that isn't returned or used later.

I'm sure some of the brilliant minds here will look at this query and know what it means instantly, but I'm completely lost as to how this works, so I would love it if anyone who has any insight could share it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this isn't RPG/RPGLE or straight SQL on what is now called the IBM i.

Sequel is a third party product now owned by Help-systems
https://www.helpsystems.com/product-lines/sequel

From what I've heard, it's a nice tool, but the syntax is product specific.

My somewhat educated guesses, having some 25 years on the platform, but no experience with the Sequel product, agrees with what you think is going on.

- LEN(6,2) --> resizing the result column.  `cast (sum(prcval) as numeric(6,2))`
- .# --> a strange way to alias the table
- &[text], &&[text] --> passed in parameters, the && escaped because of the double quotes.

`WDATA` is the only stumper...a bit of googling seems to indicate that it's used to include "hidden" columns that don't show in the "main" results screen.  Possibly used in a header/filter on the page?

Comment: You actually helped me solve this by telling me it _isn't_ part of DB2 - I thought Sequel Data Access was a package of functions, I didn't realize it was its own reporting software. I went and looked at documentation specifically for Sequel Data Access and found answers to all four of my questions at http://static.helpsystems.com/sequel/web-manuals-help/SEQ%2011%20SQL%20Ref%20UG.pdf?_ga=2.255803208.1196083854.1499094099-934577074.1499094099.

Comment: Also to add for anyone who comes across this in the future, here are the answers and relevant locations in the PDF above:  

* LEN resizes a field and trims decimal places (bottom of page 53)  

* WDATA is "working data" and allows data to be modified or used in Sequel Data Access without returning it in the result set (bottom of page 52)  

* The "column.#" field qualification is similar to aliasing as "table.column" - in the query I was using it wasn't actually necessary since the columns were named different (page 6)  

* Variables are &name, or &&name to escape (page 120, #9)